# How do I follow a hyperlink in Excel and close the originating file?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a series of files with names that follow a naming convention that includes a week ending date.
For example: **2020 Field - PP 28 - 07-05.xlsm**

I have a cell that increments this value and acts as a hyperlink to the next file  and one that hyperlinks to the previous file.  This works flawlessly.  The only drawback is that you end up with all the files still open draining resources.

Sometimes I do want several open at once but I would like to have the option to close the originating file when moving to the next file.

I was thinking to create a button that calls VBA code to follow the hyperlink and close the file, while the existing cell will act as it does and open the file without closing the current one. One of each for ***Next*** and one of each for ***Previous***

I have tried to dabble a bit with some code but I don't know enough VB to blow my nose.

I came up with this, but since it doesn't work I know there will be more to it:

```
Sub CommandButton1()

    Workbooks.Open Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 10).Value
    ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=True
    
End Sub
```

In case it is needed, the formula in the cell is this:

```
=HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE(YEAR(C1)," Field - PP ",IF((WEEKNUM(C1+14,2))<10,0,""),WEEKNUM(C1+14,2)," - ",IF(MONTH(C1+7)<10,"0"&MONTH(C1+7),MONTH(C1+7)),"-",IF(DAY(C1+7)<10,"0"&DAY(C1+7),DAY(C1+7)),".xlsm"),"Next PP")
```

C1 being the cell with the current files week ending date.

Some help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @Tim Williams code works great but I would like to add code that if the sheet is protected, the macro does not work.  Is that possible?  Otherwise an error is displayed whereas it would be better to just not have the button active.

Comment: I added this code that I found elsewhere on stackoverflow and it solved the second problem: ``If ActiveSheet.ProtectContents = True Then
        Exit Sub
        End If``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Sub CommandButton1()
    Dim dt, f
    dt = ActiveSheet.Range("C1").Value
    f = Format(dt, "yyyy") & " Field - PP " & Format(dt + 14, "ww") & _
        " - " & Format(dt + 7, "mm") & " - " & Format(dt + 7, "dd") & ".xlsm"
    Debug.Print "Opening: " & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & f
    Workbooks.Open ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & f
    ThisWorkbook.Close savechanges:=True
End Sub
```